# Offline updating various Ubuntu versions

Tags: apt, updates, versions, offline

If I am looking to provide an offline update for several Ubuntu Linux devices using varying Ubuntu versions, how can I use one update file to standardize them all to the latest release?

I've seen that you can generate a sig file to then use apt-offline to update the outdated packages, but would this only work for one system at a time?

For example, I have two Ubuntu devices. One at 22.04.1 and one at 20.04. My goal is to have one master file on a USB loaded with the latest 22.04.3 software update to be applied to both systems in order to bring them to the same version. How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: From what I read online, the apt-offline process works for one computer at a time. First you run the command on one computer to generate the list of apps versions etc. (the signature file) then you take that sig file to another computer connected to the internet and run the command again on that computer to create a "bundle" of downloaded updates based on the signature file created in the first step. Third you run the command the third time on the first offline computer to install the updates from the bundle. Repeat as needed.

Comment: Another way is to: create a virtual machine that can be connected to the internet. Update the virtual machine. Copy the contents of `/var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb` from the virtual machine to a real USB drive. Use `sudo apt install /path/to/USB/*deb` to install all the updates. This could work for both Ubuntu 22.04. Create a new VM for Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apt-cdrom` to add a path, after adding the device to `/etc/fstab`.

```bash
sudo apt-cdrom -m -d=/media/usbstick add
```

For a more flexible setup, there is also the option to mount e.g. iso as an loop device. e.g.

```
sudo mount -o loop /media/loopdev /path/to/image.iso
```